# Bash - Install script with user input - inside formatting?

Tags: bash, shell

Display:

```
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
   |                                                                    | 
   |  [*] User Input:                                                   | 
   |                                                                    | 
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Code:

```
echo "   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ "
echo "   |                                                                    | "
echo "   |  [*] User Input:                                                   | "
echo "   |                                                                    | "
echo "   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ "
```

How would I put a user input into that box? So when they type their response, it shows up after the "User Input:" and then pull the "read input" into the rest of the script? I've tried various forms of putting the formatting code around a "read input" but it just keeps breaking. I suspect that there's a different way to do this.

Comment: You need to have a non-blocking read (i.e. doesn't require the enter key). Look into `read -n 1` (reads one keypress) and carriage returns for reprinting the display.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going with that, and that will prove useful later in the script. However, I'm looking for something else. The "User Input" is just example text, it will actually be something like "Select your IP to bind to" -- Maybe Dialog would be better for this?

Comment: maybe look at `select` for choosing from a menu?

Comment: Installation scripts that ask for user input, more if doing it in some non-standard wy, are a *very* bad idea. Think of automated installations, perhaps on a farm of machines in a computer lab...

Comment: Like @vonbrand points out, please, for the love of what is holy, don't roll your own, custom installation scripts. That being said, `dialog` is really what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I agree with others that you shouldn't be creating
interactive scripts. These are annoying (hard to reuse from other
scripts). Make sure you also accept the same values from command line
arguments (i.e. myscript --some-flag value1 value2).

Second, what's wrong with a simple:

```
IFS= read -rep 'Please, input foo> ' foo
```

Which has the benefit of giving the user the possibility of using
readline's history (bash).

Third, if you really want something interactive with 'windows', use
dialog. It was made for this!

And fourth, to accomplish what you asked for, you'll have to play with
tput. I recommend you to read the following manuals:

- tput(1): ''man 1 tput''
- terminfo(5): ''man 5 terminfo''
- termcap(5): ''man 5 termcap''

This sample script should give you an idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

message=$'
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
   |                                                                    | 
   |  [*] User Input:                                                   | 
   |                                                                    | 
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
'

# trim the the leading and trailing unwanted whitespace
message=${message#*$'\n'}
message=${message%$'\n'*}

# clear the terminal
tput reset

# write the message to the terminal
printf '%s\n' "$message"

# save the cursor position, we're going to jump!
tput sc

# this is the string from the beginning of message up to the ':'
# character (not including ':')
up_to_colon="${message%:*}"

# the number of linefeeds in $up_to_colon will help us determine the
# number of rows (i.e. if the first line is row 0, the line where the
# ':' was will be the number of linefeeds).
linefeeds=${up_to_colon//[!$'\n']/}
row=${#linefeeds}

# we'll remove from the beginning to the last linefeed, leaving only
# the line where ':' was. The length of the remaining string will
# represent the position of the ':' (minus one, because strings are
# zero indexed). We'll shift it by two to end up two characters after
# the ':'. So instead of having:
# :[cursor]
# we will have
# : [cursor]
# (IMO this is nicer)
just_colon_line=${up_to_colon##*$'\n'}
column=$((${#just_colon_line} + 2))

# jump to the computed position.
tput cup "$row" "$column"

# ask the value from the user.
IFS= read -r value

# jump back to the end of $message
tput rc

# and the user typed:
printf "User's input was: %s\n" "$value"
```

This is how a sample run looks:

```
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
   |                                                                    | 
   |  [*] User Input: My name is Neo                                    | 
   |                                                                    | 
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
User's input was: My name is Neo
dualbus@debian ~ %
```

note: the tput reset clears the previous stuff, which makes it easier to jump
to a specific (row,column), because message will be the only thing on
the screen. If you want to keep the previous text, you'll have to
query the current (row,column) and do some math to find out where to
jump. IMO boring stuff!